# Java Cards Class

Tags: java

I've just started learning Java at Oracle and I got into this exercise:

> "Write a class whose instances represent a single playing card from a
>   deck of cards. Playing cards have two distinguishing properties: rank
>   and suit."

Is this a good way of solving it?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Card{

protected static final String[] Suits = {"spades", "clubs", "hearts", "diamonds"};
protected static final String[] Ranks = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};

private String cardRank;
private String cardSuit;

public Card(){

    int randomRank = (int) (Math.random() * Ranks.length);
    int randomSuit = (int) (Math.random() * Suits.length);

    cardRank = Ranks[randomRank];
    cardSuit = Suits[randomSuit];

}

public Card(String cardRank, String cardSuit){
    cardRank = cardRank.toLowerCase();
    cardSuit = cardSuit.toLowerCase();

    if(Arrays.asList(Ranks).contains(cardRank)) this.cardRank = cardRank;
    else this.cardRank = "Invalid Rank";

    if(Arrays.asList(Suits).contains(cardSuit)) this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
    else this.cardSuit = "Invalid Suit";

}

public void getCardRank(){
    System.out.print(cardRank);
}

public void getCardSuit(){
    System.out.print(cardSuit);
}

public void sayCard(){
    getCardSuit();
    System.out.print(" ");
    getCardRank();
    System.out.println("");
}

public void setCardRank(String cardRank){
   if(Arrays.asList(Ranks).contains(cardRank)) this.cardRank = cardRank;
}

public void setCardSuit(String cardSuit){
   if(Arrays.asList(Suits).contains(cardSuit)) this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
}


}
```

Comment: You are missing 'diamonds', and you can probably make use of enums.

Comment: You can use setters in constructor instead of writing same if conditions.

Comment: @Rajesh Yeah! You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the basic fact it works I think there are multiple style and design problems.

1. Suits and Ranks should most likely be `Enum` instead of a static `String` array defined for performance as well as clarity. Problem is when other classes need to refer to them they could only refer as String array as well; then you have no protection to the content i.e. someone else could easily change the content.
2. Your cardRank and cardSuite really should be `final` since they won't change after construction.
3. Your constructor with randomization should call the other constructor with parameters instead of implementing the assignment on its own.
4. Your method naming is problematic. `getXXX()` usually means really to get the value but your method signature is `void`. You should return the value and let others decide what to do with it i.e. printing; If your method is sorely intending to print the value, rename them into `printXXX()`.